# Rota privada nao verifica se o usuário esta logado ou nao

Tags: javascript, html, react

Bom dia, estou tentando verificar se o usuario esta logado ou nao, possuo um endpoint que me devolve um token, no front estou pegando esse token e fazendo essa verificação, o problema é que mesmo apagando o token e tentando acessar a rota que era para estar privada ele consegue acessa, ao consolar ele retorna uma promisse pendente, porem nao sei porque ela esta pendente, ja que estou usando async e await

No arquivo abaixo possuo o meu service de verificação se ele esta logado ou nao.

```js
import axios from "../cross-cutting/data-access";

export default {
    isSignedIn: async () => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: { Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") }
            }
            const response = await axios.post("/login/verifyToken", config);

            if (response.status === 200) {
                return true
            } else return false;

        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Logo abaixo esta o meu codigo onde faço a requisição para esse endpoint, o problema mesmo é nessa função que eu chamei de "teste", ela esta retornando uma promisse pendente

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


import Login from "./common-components/login";
import Home from "./Home";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import service from './services/login'

export default function Routes() {
  async function teste() {
    try {
      let response = await service.isSignedIn()
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route
          render={props =>
            teste() ? (
              <Panel />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
              )
          }
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Ao apagar o token e acessar a rota que era para estar protegida, a api detorna 401, mas ainda sim é possivel acessar a rota

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao consolar a função "teste" ele retorna uma promisse pendente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puderem me dizer o que eu estou fazendo de errado ficarei grato, Obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer ao em vez de passar no header, realizar uma validação previa fora do envio para a rota, dai caso não possua autenticação nem vai chamar a rota. Não sei se isso é válido para você mas espero ter ajudado.